# How to get Transformer-based recommendation model to predict new movies

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, transformer-model

I'm trying to run the Behavior Sequence Transformer model in https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/structured_data/ipynb/movielens_recommendations_transformers.ipynb to predict the next movie to watch, based on previous movie ratings.

I've got the code in the Colab notebook running correctly, but can't seem to get any meaningful predictions out of it.

Here's the output of model.input_shape:

```
{'user_id': (None, 1), 'sequence_movie_ids': (None, 3), 'target_movie_id': (None, 1), 'sequence_ratings': (None, 3), 'sex': (None, 1), 'age_group': (None, 1), 'occupation': (None, 1)}
```

And here's the code I'm using for predictions:

```
# Load the latest 3 movies you watched and gave them all a rating of 4
latest_movies = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [0],
    'sequence_movie_ids': [[1, 2, 3]],
    'target_movie_id': [0],
    'sequence_ratings': [[4.0, 4.0, 4.0]],
    'sex': [0],
    'age_group': [0],
    'occupation': [0]
})

# Predict the next movie to watch
next_movie = model.predict(input_data)
print(next_movie)
```

However, this leads to the following error message:

```
Node: 'model/Cast'
Cast int32 to string is not supported
     [[{{node model/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_40501]
```

I've also tried to convert input_data to tensors:

```
# Prepare the input data
input_data = {
    'user_id': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['user_id'], dtype=tf.int32),
    'sequence_movie_ids': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['sequence_movie_ids'], dtype=tf.int32),
    'target_movie_id': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['target_movie_id'], dtype=tf.int32),
    'sequence_ratings': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['sequence_ratings'], dtype=tf.float32),
    'sex': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['sex'], dtype=tf.int32),
    'age_group': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['age_group'], dtype=tf.int32),
    'occupation': tf.convert_to_tensor(latest_movies['occupation'], dtype=tf.int32)
}
```

But this fails as well, with error message:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can we get this model to make predictions?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; there was a function called '`create_model_inputs()`' which enabled me to deduce the structure of the input data.

The working code is below. Note that the values in input_data are derived from the test_data.csv and train_data.csv files, and need to be strings.

```
# Create the input dictionary. Get example values from the test_data.csv or train_data.csv files. 
input_data = {
    "user_id": np.array(["user_1"]),
    "sequence_movie_ids": np.array([["movie_531", "movie_532", "movie_533"]]),
    "target_movie_id": np.array(["movie_534"]),
    "sequence_ratings": np.array([[4.0, 1.0, 5.0]]),
    "sex": np.array(["M"]),
    "age_group": np.array(["group_35"]),
    "occupation": np.array(["occupation_1"])
}

# Predict the next movie to watch
next_movie = model.predict(input_data)
print(next_movie)
```